# Xamarin Hiding and showing Flyout Item based on value

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am currently learning xamarin forms bits by bits when I had this problem. I wanna make an app where a certain flyout item will be hidden if the user is not an admin. However, even after a successful login of an admin, the flyout item stays hidden. Here's the simplified version of the app.

Here's my code for AppShell.xaml:

```
<Shell.BindingContext>
     <viewmodel:AppShellViewModel></viewmodel:AppShellViewModel>
 </Shell.BindingContext>
 <ShellItem Route="LoginPage" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False">
     <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:LoginPage}"/>
 </ShellItem>
 <FlyoutItem Title="Page 1">
     <ShellContent Route="Page" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:Page}"/>
 </FlyoutItem>
 <FlyoutItem Title="Page 2" IsVisible="{Binding isAdmin}">
     <ShellContent Route="Page2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:Page2}"/>
 </FlyoutItem>
 <MenuItem Text="isAdmin?" Command="{Binding checkCommand}"/>
```

AppShellViewModel.cs:

```
public class AppShellViewModel: BindableObject
 {
     public AppShellViewModel()
     {
         MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginViewModel>(this, message: "user", (sender) => {
             _isAdmin = false;
         });
         MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginViewModel>(this, message: "admin", (sender) => {
             _isAdmin = true;
         });
         checkCommand = new Command(async () => await checkAdmin());
     }
     private bool _isAdmin;
     public bool isAdmin
     {
         get { return _isAdmin; }
         set
         {
             _isAdmin = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
     public ICommand checkCommand { get; }
     private async Task checkAdmin()
     {
         string str = $"isAdmin: {_isAdmin}";
         await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", str, "OK");
     }
 }
```

As I've said, the `isAdmin` will be modified through login method. if the user enter 'admin', isAdmin will be set to true and if it's 'user', false.

Here's my LoginPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
     <viewmodel:LoginViewModel></viewmodel:LoginViewModel>
 </ContentPage.BindingContext>
 <ContentPage.Content>
     <StackLayout>
         <Entry Text="{Binding user}"/>
         <Button Text="Login" Command="{Binding loginCommand}"/>
     </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage.Content>
```

Here's my LoginViewModel.cs :

```
public class LoginViewModel: BindableObject
 {
     public LoginViewModel()
     {
         loginCommand = new Command(async () => await LoginFunc());
     }
     public ICommand loginCommand { get; }
     string _user;
     public string user
     {
         get => _user;
         set
         {
             _user = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
    
     private async Task LoginFunc()
     {
         if(_user != null)
         {
             MessagingCenter.Send<LoginViewModel>(this, _user);
             await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(Page)}");
         }
     }
 }
```

As per code above, I manage (correct me if my method is wrong) to modify the `isAdmin` by using `MessagingCenter`, which can be shown if I click the "isAdmin?" MenuItem.

I don't know if the `isVisible` is working even after the `isAdmin` property is change (when i tried to initialize `isAdmin = true`, the flyout item keeps showing even if the user is not an admin).

I would be grateful for any help/tips I will receive.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you confirm if your Messaging Center Subscriber is getting called?

Comment: @FreakyAli I created a command that will display if `isAdmin` is changing using `<MenuItem Text="isAdmin?" Command="{Binding checkCommand}"/>`
When I click 'isAdmin?' in the LoginPage, `isAdmin = false`, and when I click it again after a successful login, it displays `isAdmin = true`. So yeah, I think the Messaging Center is working just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that you are not updating the Property but the Field which leads to OnPropertyChanged being never called and hence your UI is never updated.

```
 public AppShellViewModel()
 {
     MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginViewModel>(this, message: "user", (sender) => {
         isAdmin = false;
     });
     MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginViewModel>(this, message: "admin", (sender) => {
         isAdmin = true;
     });
     checkCommand = new Command(async () => await checkAdmin());
 }
```

Good luck!

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot :D now I can keep my AppShell ViewModel T_T

Answer (score 0):

Just wanna share that I've just solve this problem. This is how:

1. I removed the AppShellViewModel.cs completely and put its content in the AppShell.xaml.cs (the code behind)
2. Instead of using MessagingCenter, I just used the following (code is included in the login function)

```
if(_user == "admin")
{
(Shell.Current as AppShell).isAdmin = true;
}
else
{
(Shell.Current as AppShell).isAdmin = false;
}
```

However, I'm still looking for other solutions so that I can separate the AppShell view and its viewmodel.
So if you have others solutions, kindly post it here ^_^. Thank you

Comment: I think i added the solution that will work..